# How to change string + in url to not space words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I have URL like this `http://localhost/?ID=My+Name`

And i must share the URL to whatsapp message using javascript. The function share to whatsapp is already, but i have some issue.

When redirected to whatsapp app, the URL changed to `http://localhost/?ID=My Name`, its not same with my expectation. Because the url must `http://localhost/?ID=My+Name`

How i can to fixed this issue?

Comment: Is the URL being decoded somewhere?

Comment: encodeURI(Component)

Comment: did you try encodeURIComponent method ?

Comment: Using `encodeURI` the full uri or `encodeURIComponent` on the parts it is the proper way. That said you could put manually a `%20`, which will also happen if you use some enconding method, in those places. I believe a `+` should also work.

Comment: thankyou for the response. i have to change "+" to "%2B" , and the URL `http://localhost/?ID=My%2BName` then when i accessed to WhatsApp, the "%2B" changed to "+" string